# Cartesian product of n copies of an iterator with n variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, product, python-itertools

I would like to use `itertools.product` or a similar command in order to obtain the cartesian product of `n` copies of an iterator `iter` with itself, where `n` is a variable. I tried constructing it recursively by

```
import itertools

prod_iter = iter
for i in xrange(n-1):
    prod_iter = itertools.product(prod_iter,iter)
```

But starting with, say, `iter=xrange(2)`, `n=3` and running

```
for i in prod_iter:
    print i
```

I get as an output

```
((0,0),0)
((0,0),1)
((0,1),0)
...
```

and not

```
(0,0,0)
(0,0,1)
(0,1,0)
...
```

as I would like. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) has such parameter: `repeat`**.

So no need to invent it yourself, you can simply write:

```
from itertools import product

for i in product(iter, repeat=3):
    print i
```

For example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> iter = "qux"
>>> 
>>> for i in product(iter, repeat=3):
...     print i
... 
('q', 'q', 'q')
('q', 'q', 'u')
('q', 'q', 'x')
('q', 'u', 'q')
('q', 'u', 'u')
('q', 'u', 'x')
('q', 'x', 'q')
('q', 'x', 'u')
('q', 'x', 'x')
('u', 'q', 'q')
('u', 'q', 'u')
('u', 'q', 'x')
('u', 'u', 'q')
('u', 'u', 'u')
('u', 'u', 'x')
('u', 'x', 'q')
('u', 'x', 'u')
('u', 'x', 'x')
('x', 'q', 'q')
('x', 'q', 'u')
('x', 'q', 'x')
('x', 'u', 'q')
('x', 'u', 'u')
('x', 'u', 'x')
('x', 'x', 'q')
('x', 'x', 'u')
('x', 'x', 'x')
```